# How do I automate a window with dynamically generated AutomationIDs?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, automation, white-framework

I'm trying to create a troubleshooting suite for some software. It seems every time I open up said software with Visual UIA, the UI elements have different AutomationIDs. I can't use SearchCriteria.byText("") because they're all blank. How else can I get references to those textboxes?

Thank you!

Comment: Does your Textbox has Name property , will you be accessible to it?

Comment: That didn't work, but I was able to specify a textbox using .ByClass("Edit").AndIndex(0);